# register a receiver when browser is launched in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-browser

How to start a service inside receiver as soon as browser is launched by user and then get current URL user is visiting? I don't want to get into customization of browser.

I googled it a lot but didn't find a solution. Please help me out.

Thanks

-Sam

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4148739/edit

Comment: @Hardik: I don't want to use Logcat logs as READ_LOGS permissions are only used by system apps. Do we have another way around?

Comment: i want to took a look into @Aimeric answer not accepted one. see Aimeric answer :)

Comment: Actually I have to get current URL as soon as browser is launched and alert the user accordingly. In a timely loop (which @Aimeric suggests) it may miss few urls after launch.

Comment: ASFAIK There no other way to do this...